# IIS 6.0 FTP Folder Permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, ftp

I have a IIS FTP website setup like this

```
\ftp\users\domain\public\public
```

Software that runs on clients computers logs into the FTP server by specifying `domain\public` and moving to `public`, it then uploads or downloads files / folders into that area.

I want to **restrict** permissions on `\ftp\users\domain\public` so that nothing/nobody can write files or folders here, **only** to `\ftp\users\domain\public\public`.

I setup the NTFS permissions of the folder to remove domain\users, public and server\users to not have modify right, yet I can still upload/modify files.

I have disabled inheritance from the parent folder of \ftp\users\domain\public as well.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

P.S I know this is a stupid setup and makes no sense, it's some bizarre legacy application that I need to migrate to a safer environment until it can be replaced.

Comment: My search for an answer is not looking good, it appears that IIS Virtual Directory permissions override that of NTFS permissions, which breaks the usual rule of "The most restrictive set of permissions enforced are followed". It's appearing that I will have to continue using this solution until a future upgrade to new FTP platform that can support complex permissions will be the solution.

Comment: I have implemented a different FTP solution that follows NTFS permissions, I'll leave this question open in case anyone can confirm / deny my previous comment.

Comment: can we get a screen shot of the NTFS permissions? for \ftp\users\domain?  Then can see some of your FTP configs?  Cleansed of course...

Comment: I would recommend just downloading FileZilla FTP server. Much easier to set up users/permissions from the gui and even FTPS. And if you're interested in SSH/SFTP, there's a fully working implementation of OpenSSH for Windows (tested it on 2012 R2): https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/12_22_2015

Answer (score 1):

Are you following [Creating a New FTP Site with Isolate Users Using Active Directory Mode (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/29753aec-35b7-4929-b0a5-846474f627ba.mspx?mfr=true), if yes then you will have to follow the article [Hosting Multiple FTP Sites with FTP User Isolation (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b63de8ef-e3c5-456d-a8ca-7af4198819d4.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Hi There Vivek, It is a single FTP site with user isolation.